# A question on Itō's formula.

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes

This question  is taken fron the book
''Stochastic Differential Equations in Infinite Dimensions'' by
Leszek Gawarecki and Vidyadhar Mandrekar.

Let $K$ be any separable Hilbert space with $\{f_k\}$ as its ONB.

$W$ be a K-valued $Q$-Wiener process define on filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F_t}\}_t, \mathbb{P})$

A part of the Itō's Formula on page 67, specifically on the following equation.

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
  \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \big\langle u_{xx} (t_j, W_{t_j})(\Delta W_j), \Delta W_j\big\rangle_K \to \displaystyle\int_0^t \text{tr}\big[u_{xx}(s,W_s)Q \big] ds \hspace{10pt}    (1)
\end{equation}
in probability $\mathbb{P}$.

To me (uncertain, correct me if im wrong), for each $\omega$, the integral on the right integral as Riemann type
for the bounded integrand in $\displaystyle\int_0^t\text{tr}[u_{xx}(s, W_s)Q] ds$  where  $\Delta W_j=W_{t+1}-W_t$.

Q1: is how can we guarantee that for each $\omega$, $\text{tr}[u_{xx}(s, W_s)Q]$ is finite? since it is only given that $Q:K\to K$ with $\text{tr}Q <\infty$ and $u_{xx}(s,W_s)$ is in $L(K,K)$.

As I went in detail through the proof of this equation:

The author ends the proof using the following facts:
As $\Delta t_i\to 0$, $\mathbb{E}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (\langle 1_j^N u_{xx} (t_j,W_{t_j})(\Delta W_j), \Delta W_j\rangle_K- \text{tr}(1_j^N u_{xx}(t_j,W_{t_j})\Delta t_j) )   \Big)^2\to 0$ $\hspace{10pt}$    (2)

and as $N\to \infty$,
$\mathbb{P}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (1-1_j^N)(\langle u_{xx} (t_j,W_{t_j})(\Delta W_j), \Delta W_j\rangle_K)- \text{tr}(1_j^N u_{xx}(t_j,W_{t_j}\Delta t_j) ) \neq 0  \Big)\to 0$ $\hspace{10pt}$   (3)

I can't really figure out how how (2) and (3) even related the conclusion.

Q2: Is a Riemann type integral?..

I'm trying to learn new concepts and some techniques involve in the formulation.

Any insight is highly appreciated..